# Dialogue Box With AlarmManager Service

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am using `AlarmManager` to do a service , I need to display a `Dialog` box with input field.I can `Toast` Messages in the same case(With that service) , but I am suffering to display the `Dialog` box.What can I do? 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you paste some code sample??...

Answer (score 0):

Use a handler to to show dialog inside service

```
//call this for dispaly dialog
notificationMessageHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);


 //handler for dialog

 private Handler notificationMessageHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {




        AlertDialog dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                IngogoPassengerApp.getCurrentTopActivity())
                .setTitle("Test")
                .setMessage("message")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Close",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {}
                        }).create();

        dlg.show();


    }
};
```